# dynamically adding rows to google line chart off set interval ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-visualization

how do I dynamically add rows to the google line chart on each time the data is pulled by ajax call of set intervals ?

I have this code

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'Day');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Guardians of the Galaxy');
  data.addColumn('number', 'The Avengers');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Transformers: Age of Extinction');

  data.addRows([
    [1,  37.8, 80.8, 41.8],
    [2,  30.9, 69.5, 32.4],
    [3,  25.4,   57, 25.7],
    [4,  11.7, 18.8, 10.5],
    [5,  11.9, 17.6, 10.4],
    [6,   8.8, 13.6,  7.7],
    [7,   7.6, 12.3,  9.6],
    [8,  12.3, 29.2, 10.6],
    [9,  16.9, 42.9, 14.8],
    [10, 12.8, 30.9, 11.6],
    [11,  5.3,  7.9,  4.7],
    [12,  6.6,  8.4,  5.2],
    [13,  4.8,  6.3,  3.6],
    [14,  4.2,  6.2,  3.4]
  ]);

  var options = {
    chart: {
      title: 'Box Office Earnings in First Two Weeks of Opening',
      subtitle: 'in millions of dollars (USD)'
    },
    width: 900,
    height: 500
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

now instead of I want dynamic adding of rows as soon as page is loaded and after set interval should add new values fetched from ajax query like this:

```
setInterval(ajaxCall, 300000); //300000 MS == 5 minutes

function ajaxCall() {

     $.ajax({
                 type: "GET",
                 crossDomain: true,
                 dataType: "json",
                 data: {
                    format: 'json'
                        },
                 url: 'http://192.168.1.156:8025/json',
                 success: function(jsondata) {
                    jsn = JSON.stringify(jsondata, undefined, 2);

                    // put data in  jsn to google line chart.

                    // Above Google Line chart to load here
                    // data = new google.visualization.DataTable();


                        //  dynamically add rows on each fetch success of ajax call
                 }
            }); 
    //do your AJAX stuff here
}


{"arduino" : [{"location" : "Outdoor" , "temperatureInC" : "22.20" , "temperatureInF" : "71.96" , "dewPoint_in_Fahr" : "62.66" , "dewPoint_in_Cel" : "13.54" , "heat_index__in_Fahr" : "71.61" , "heat_index_in_Cel" : "22.00" , "humidity":"58"} , {"location" : "Drawing Room" , "temperatureInC" : "25.80" , "temperatureInF" : "78.44" , "dewPoint_in_Fahr" : "62.66" , "dewPoint_in_Cel" : "17.03" , "heat_index__in_Fahr" : "78.73" , "heat_index_in_Cel" : "25.96" , "humidity" : "58.50"}] , "pots" : [{"pot1" : "0"}]}
```

Comment: will you please share a sample of `jsondata` as returned by ajax?

Comment: @WhiteHat  I have added sample data , I want to graph data of temperature and humidity of 1st item in array of `arduino` key .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('45', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'Update');
  data.addColumn('number', 'temperatureInC');
  data.addColumn('number', 'temperatureInF');
  data.addColumn('number', 'humidity');

  var options = {
    chart: {
      title: 'temperature vs. humidity'
    },
    width: 900,
    height: 500
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));
  ajaxCall();
  setInterval(ajaxCall, 5000); //300000 MS == 5 minutes
  function ajaxCall() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      crossDomain: true,
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        format: 'json'
      },
      url: 'http://san.gotdns.ch:8025/json',
    }).done(function (jsonData) {
      var chartData = jsonData.arduino;
      if (chartData.length > 0) {
        data.addRow([
          data.getNumberOfRows() + 1,
          parseFloat(chartData[0].temperatureInC),
          parseFloat(chartData[0].temperatureInF),
          parseFloat(chartData[0].humidity)
        ]);
      }
      chart.draw(data, options);
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="linechart_material"></div>
```

Comment: hope this helps -- fyi: _material_ `Line` charts will not plot a single row of data -- switch to _core_ `LineChart` to see points for a single row...

Comment: when I run this code I get this error: `{
  "message": "Error: one or more fonts could not be loaded.",
  "filename": "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/45.1/js/jsapi_compiled_ui_module.js",
  "lineno": 181,
  "colno": 201
}`

Comment: try changing the version here --> `google.charts.load('current'` -- start with latest frozen version `'45'`, you can go back to `'42'` -- `google.charts.load('45'`

Comment: can you please update your answer with `current` to `45` and `Line` to `LineChart` ?

Comment: thanks I accept however I found as soon as the second iteration plots the data the time line at bottom disappears.

Comment: I wrote function that returns time that gets punched every time solved the problem.

Comment: how are you able to display the graph from my URL onto jsfiddle , when I try in my jsfiddle I get this error : `[Warning] [blocked] The page at https://jsfiddle.net/ was not allowed to display insecure content from http://san.gotdns.ch:8025/json?format=json. (jquery-1.9.1.js, line 8526, x2)
`

Comment: actually, i haven't tried on jsfiddle, just here. saw the url in the other question, seemed to work...